# Using Azure Event Grid for event-based communication between microservices

Tags: microservices, azureservicebus, azure-eventgrid

I'm looking to implement a event-based communication pattern between my microservices and I'm looking to use **Azure Service Bus** to handle the messaging.  In the examples I've seen so far (e.g. Microsoft's eShopOnContainers) the events are handled by a common library that handles the event subscription/publishing.  I'm wondering if the common library could be replaced with Azure's **Event Grid** service (I realise this could generate an opinion-based answer, so please remove this question if it is deemed so)?

I like how Event Grid has retry capabilities, receives events from Azure Service Bus, push-like functionality (meaning my microservice doesn't need to poll), as well as other features, so in my mind it seems like a good fit.  However, I'm fairly new to the event-based communication concept so I'm well aware I could be missing something.

If Azure Event Grid could be used to handle the events, is it possible to send the event to a Web Api endpoint?  Once again, the examples I've seen so far all send the event to a Azure Function trigger, but I'm not planning on using any Azure Functions for my microservices.

If anyone had any examples they could point me to where Azure Service Bus and Event Grid were used for communication between microservices, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I do recommend to read document https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services included the first two articles in the Next steps. Note, that the AEG emitting events for Azure Service Bus entity, see more details in the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-to-event-grid-integration-concept, also your solution should be considered using the Azure Function as a valid service of the serverless evet driven architecture, for instance, forwarding an event to the *SignalR Service* which is a perfect candidate for mobile and web apps

Comment: Thanks @RomanKiss for those links.  I believe the crossover scenario might be what I'm looking at (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/messaging#crossover-scenarios).  With regards to Azure Functions, my issue with this is that by placing it in front of my Web Api it introduces another point of failure (very unlikely but I must allow for this) in the whole microservice chain.